# Creating a wrapper inside of a MarionetteJS ComspositeView

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, grid, marionette

Hello dear SO users and contributers. I'm unsure on how to manipulate compositeViews using the JS framework MarionetteJS based on BackboneJS. Hopefully someone will be able to give me some advice on how to continue.

**The application context:** The application I'm building is a GRID that can accept draggable items. This grid is being build using two *CompositeView*'s to build the rows within the page *section* and an *ItemView* for each field that's actually represented on the website.

**The application views:** I posses a gridView that has a collection of gridModels which get split over multiple rows in the initialize method. This generates a *section* in the HTML that will hold the GRID. The gridRowView will generate a div with the class 'day' for each row within the gridView build from all of the gridItems.

> It has been mentioned that in a previous question relating my GRID that a treeView is probably more suitable for the purposes. But I feel this does not concern the scope of my question.

```
planboard.gridItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    model: planboard.gridModel,
    collection: planboard.gridCollection,
    template: "#grid-item-template",
    onShow: function() {
        //code to plan dropped orders
    }
});
planboard.gridRowView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#grid-row-template",
    itemView: planboard.gridItemView,
    itemViewContainer: "div.day",
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(_.toArray(this.model.attributes));
    }
});
planboard.gridView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#grid-template",
    itemView: planboard.gridRowView,
    tagName: "section",
    initialize: function() {
        var grid = this.collection.groupBy(function(list, iterator) {
            return Math.floor(iterator / collums); // 4 == number of columns
        });
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(_.toArray(grid));
    }
});
```

**The application templates:**

```
<!-- Grid templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="grid-item-template">
    <div class="gridItem droppable" id="{{cid}}"><b>{{data}}</b></div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="grid-row-template">
    <div class="day"></div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="grid-template">
    <section></section>
</script>
```

**The problem:** The code below (minus the event wrapper) resembles code as structured in the DOM. As you can see the views generate the expected result. I am however in a spot where I need to use positioning to place items on the GRID. To do this I've taken the start of div container around the section (the start of the GRID).

Although this works, this becomes a problem once scroll-bars are introduced. Since the start position of the GRID does not actualy change you can scroll down but the orders will always remain on the same position off the screen.

**Possible solution:** Watching the Google Calendar I've realized that they use an additional event-wrapper inside of their rows for positioning. This seems logical to me since then the offset to determine the position from would no longer be the start of your GRID, but rather the start of row (class 'day'). This should solve the problem that scroll-bars could pose.

In my mind this would look something like the code below:

```
<section>
<div> <!-- wrapper generated by framework -->
<div class="day">
    <div class="event-x"> <!-- used as offset for positioning -->
       <div id="c39" class="gridItem droppable"> <!-- grid column --></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
</section>
```

**My question:** Since my row (the div with class 'day') is automatically generated by the MarionetteJS CompsositeView I am unable to give this some unique value to identify it with that does not change. Having an additional event wrapper with a unique identifier would most likely solve my problem, since then I could use JQuerySelectors to get the positioning from that element.

However... Marionette practically generates the wrapper for me and I'm unsure how to add a wrapper inside of this row with a unique on top of this. Do any of you (who have experience with MarionetteJS or Backbone) have any idea how to go about this?

Am I even looking in the right direction? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to assign unique id / class to wrapper, generated by `View`, following answer might help. Note, that it actually doesn't any additional wrapper, it is just way to add attributes to automatically generated wrappers.

You can define attributes for `View` (or anything, that extends it e.g. `CompositeView`). These attributes will be automatically assigned to wrapper element. You can define them in [extend](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend) or as a [function or hash](http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes)

If you need just static identifier, use first approach:

```
planboard.gridRowView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#grid-row-template",
    itemView: planboard.gridItemView,
    itemViewContainer: "div.day",
    id: "some-id",
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(_.toArray(this.model.attributes));
    }
});
```

If you need to generate id based on model, use second approach:

```
planboard.gridRowView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#grid-row-template",
    itemView: planboard.gridItemView,
    itemViewContainer: "div.day",
    attributes: function() {
        return {
            id: this.model.get("id") // or something like this
        };
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(_.toArray(this.model.attributes));
    }
});
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want. I can get the first and second approach to work just fine. But this applies the ID to the wrapper 'around' the row-template rather then on the actual div with the "div.day" class.